# is it possible to deposit Avax into brownie generated account? [brownie]

Tags: brownie, avax

I like to ask if I generate a new account in brownie, can I deposit avax into it? I am wondering because many platforms warn about sending coins to the wrong type of address. I understand I can deposit eth and erc-20 tokens into the brownie accounts, but what about native coins of other networks, like avax, and others like matic?

Sorry for my noob question, very new in the web3 space. Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating any new account comes down to generating a new Private key.

Once generated, it can be used on multiple networks (Because the Private key is nothing more than a random collection of 256 bits), and most blockchain networks work with 256bit private keys. Actually, I don't know of ANY large public network that isn't using 256bit Private key and 160Bit Public address.

So any new account you **generated** using Browne will work on any network. And you will be able to use it on the Avalanche network and deposit Avax there.

*HOWEVER*: **DON'T** use accounts brownie generated itself for testing/development, (the ones you might have used for development) because those Private keys are public and everyone knows them **!!!!**

If anything I wrote is unclear to you, or it feels like something is missing. Please ask away before deciding to use keys/addresses generated in brownie

Comment: Thank you very much sir. You have made it clear to understand!

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about depositing mainnet avax into a brownie account, that would not be advised. Test accounts have the small possibility of multiple people having the same account and private key.

If you mean that you would like to use the avax testnet, here is an example of adding a new network to brownie.

https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/network-management.html#adding-a-new-network

and here is a link to the avax testnet info:

https://docs.avax.network/quickstart/fuji-workflow#set-up-fuji-network-on-metamask-optional